# Is there a term for the device of repeating the exact same word twice immediately to emphasize its sincerity or power?

Tags: terminology, literary-device

I already know the term *anaphora* exists for repeating the same word for emphasis. I'm specifically interested in a term for repeating a word twice without additional clarification to express that something is especially strong or genuine.

Examples

> "Do you like her, or do you *like* like her?"

> "Are you making quick bread, or are you making *bread* bread?

> "I'm so excited, I got a *promotion* promotion, with a pay raise and everything!"

I don't know that I've ever seen this in formal prose; it seems unique to spoken English, but if anyone knows of any written examples please add them. If no term already exists, I'd like to coin the term "*duplication* duplication," to distinguish it from ordinary duplication.

Comment: 1) 'duplication duplication' is what I'm gonna call it even if there is an 'official' way to say it 2) [that's not at all what anaphora is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)), 3) [oh snap yes it is!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(rhetoric)) 4) the general linguistic term is ['reduplication'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called [Contrastive focus reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_focus_reduplication). It's pretty easy to find by searching for "*like* like", the most common example. (*"like like" linguistics*, to be exact.)

The examples from the Wikipedia article are:

- "I'll make the tuna salad and you make the *salad* salad."
- "How do they know it's turkey bacon and not *bacon* bacon?"
- "I'm up, I'm just not *up* up."
- "Is that carrot cheesecake or carrot *cake*-cake?"

*Duplication* duplication is a really cute description though! It doesn't quite fit with the more usual meaning, which is "literal" (unlike "*like* like" which is an exception--in that phrase, the duplication changes the meaning to a more specific one).

And to add some silliness on that note: *You will literally explode, but you won't literally literally explode, right?*

Comment: Hello, piojo. Please check for possible duplicates. 'Contrastive focus reduplication' has already been covered more than once on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough. I will do that in the future when it seems a likely common question.

Comment: It's probably best to post (before someone else does) then search for your answer in possible duplicates. _Contrastive focus reduplication_ is a more tractable search element than _device of repeating the exact same word twice immediately to emphasize its sincerity or power?_ If an obvious duplicate, you can delete your own answer.